# Python multiprocessing trouble

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn the multiprocessing module in python and I've written this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
import itertools

alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
max_length = 4
num_procs = 8
procs = []

#Function to get the combinations..Eg: if the chunk is abc:
#The combinations should be a, aa, ab,... abc, abcd, ....., b, ba,bb.....
def doSomething(inp_chunk,q):
    for letter in inp_chunk:
        for i in range(max_length-1):
            for c in itertools.combinations(alphabet,i):
                word = letter + ''.join(c)
                q.put(word)



def main():
    #Divide the alphabet in to chunks based on number of processes
    chunk_size = int(len(alphabet) / num_procs)


    q = Queue()

    #Start Processes and assign chunk of characters to each
    for i in range(num_procs):
        if i == num_procs-1:
            p = Process(target=doSomething,args=(alphabet[i*chunk_size:],q,))
        else:    
            p = Process(target=doSomething,args=(alphabet[i*chunk_size:(i*chunk_size)+chunk_size],q,))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    #Join the processes    
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    print q.get()


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

But for some reason this doesn't work. The print statement for q.get() only outputs

> a

and the processes keep running. But when I ran the code without multiprocessing, by just calling the function instead of the processes in the for loop, it worked and gave me the output. And it took like about a second.

So what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Your only getting the first element in the queue. Try wrapping the queue.get in a loop until it is empty.

Comment: @Dean Thank you! that was it. I added a while loop which breaks on Empty exception and it prints out the combinations. But, the program seems to not exit and just stay there even when I am using the join. Why is this so? and can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is only being executed once:

```
print q.get()
```

That means that only the first character put on the queue will be retrieved and printed. Put this statement in a loop to get the rest of the characters:

```
while not q.empty():
    print q.get()
```

If you're concerned about get blocked in the call to `q.get()`, try this:

```
while not q.empty():
    try:
        print q.get(block=False)
    except Queue.Empty:
        break
```

[The docs for Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.empty) state that a non-blocking call to `Queue.get()` can raise the `Queue.Empty` exception even if `Queue.empty()` returned `False`, so remember to catch the exception.